# Javascript and <p:ajax> behave strange

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, google-maps-api-3, primefaces

I have a js-function `codeAddress()` that processess the data from `address` and updates the values of `fullAddress` and `validField`.
The data of `fullAddress` and `validField` is passed by `<p:ajax>` to the backing bean, but the setter methods seem to get called one request delayed.
The `alert()` at the end of `codeAddress` shows the correct new data.
When `address` has `onchange="test()"` everything works fine an the backing beans setter methods are called as they should without any delay.
I am clueless what might be wrong here.

my jsf code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:outputScript name="jsf.js" library="javax.faces" target="head"/>
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="bugMaps.js" />
    <body onload="initialize()" />
    <h:form id="addressForm">
        <p:inputText id="address" onchange="codeAddress()">
            <p:ajax process="fullAddress validField"/>
        </p:inputText>
        <p:message id="addressValidate" for=":addressForm:validField"/>
        <p:commandButton value="submit" />
        <p:inputText id="fullAddress" value="#{addressBean.fullAddress}" />
        <p:inputText id="validField" value="#{addressBean.valid}" />
    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

my JS:

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var valid = false;
var fullAddress = "none";

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}

function test(){
    fullAddress = Math.random();
    document.getElementById('addressForm:fullAddress').value = fullAddress;
}

function codeAddress() {
    var address = (document.getElementById('addressForm:address').value + ", Germany");
    geocoder.geocode({'address' : address},function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latLong = results[0].geometry.location;
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            var country, postal_code, locality, street_number, route;
            for (i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; ++i) {
                var component = results[0].address_components[i];
                if (!locality && component.types.indexOf("locality") > -1)
                    locality = component.long_name;
                else if (!postal_code && component.types.indexOf("postal_code") > -1)
                    postal_code = component.long_name;
                else if (!country && component.types.indexOf("country") > -1)
                    country = component.long_name;
                else if (!street_number && component.types.indexOf("street_number") > -1)
                    street_number = component.long_name;
                else if (!route && component.types.indexOf("route") > -1)
                    route = component.long_name;
            }
            if (typeof latLong != "undefined"
                && typeof latitude != "undefined"
                && typeof longitude != "undefined"
                && typeof route != "undefined"
                && typeof street_number != "undefined"
                && typeof postal_code != "undefined"
                && typeof locality != "undefined"
                && typeof country != "undefined"){
                valid = true;
                fullAddress = results[0].formatted_address;
            }
            else{
                valid=false;
                fullAddress="none";
            };
        }
        else{

            valid=false;
            fullAddress="none";
        }
        document.getElementById('addressForm:fullAddress').value = fullAddress;
        document.getElementById('addressForm:validField').value = valid;
        alert(fullAddress + valid);
    });
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [geocoder is returning previously stored value when click on a marker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543621/geocoder-is-returning-previously-stored-value-when-click-on-a-marker)

Comment: @geocodezip Thank you for the hint. The problem sounds indeed a lot like mine. But am I not using the result from the callback function? The alert always displays the correct values. What do I miss? Do I need some kind of delay or actively wait for the response?

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not using the result from the callback function"?  That is the only place it is available.

Comment: @geocodezip Sorry for expressing misunderstandable. This sentence was supposed to mean "I am using the results from the callback function. Don't you think so, too, when you look at my code?" Do you have an idea, how to get it work? I would really appreciate it. :)

Comment: @geocodezip I built in a static delay now and it seems to work. Is there a way to avoid a static delay and "catch" the geocoders answer when it comes?

Comment: That is what the callback function is for.  It runs (in the client) when the data is available.  Are you transferring the data to the server before the callback runs?

Comment: @geocodezip I am not sure if I understand: The callback function is all the code in the curly bracket of the second parameter of `geocoder.geocode(request, callback)`, right? I used this before and it did not work because, as I supposed, the results were updated before the response came in. Did I understand wrongly? What do you think about the answer I added is there nonsense in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a duplicate question.
The first fault was using `<p:ajax>` to submit data that was to be altered by JS, because the ajax request is already prepared while the script is still running.
The second mistake was to use the non-cross-browser-compatible `jsf.ajax.request`.
Now I simply deleted the `<p:ajax>` and use a solution with jQuery. This function is simply called from the geocoders callback function:

```
function jsfSubmit(){
    document.getElementById('addressForm:fullAddress').value = fullAddress;
    document.getElementById('addressForm:validField').value = valid;
    $.ajax({type:'POST', data:$('#addressForm').serialize(), success: function(response) {
        if(valid){
            var destPage = 'nextPage.xhtml';
            window.location = destPage;
        }
    }});
};
```